# How to get node value from this xml?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

i use actionscript 2.0. I need to get time string from this simple xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <root>
    <time>
      2011,01,25,10,58,02
    </time>
  </root>
```

I used

```
trace(_myXml.firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue);
trace(_myXml.firstChild.firstChild[0].nodeValue);
trace(_myXml.firstChild.nodeValue);
```

but it returns ever `undefined`...

what's wrong?

Is there a way to access xml like: _`myXml.root.time.value` ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var xmlData:XML = new XML();    
xmlData.ignoreWhite = true;    
xmlData.load("nomeofyourxml.xml");

xmlData.onLoad = function():Void  {
    qtd = this.childNodes[0].childNodes.length;
    trace(qtd)
    for (i=0; i<qtd; i++) {
        _xml = this.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes;
        trace(_xml);
    }
}
```

my trace result is: (2011,01,25,10,58,02)

Comment: my problem was "xmlData.ignoreWhite = true;" that i not setted. Now works correctly. tks